# Mix audio read from two source files

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I want to mix audio read from two files (1 mp3 and 1 wav(recorded voice) file) into one file (mp3 or wav).

I have read many relevant answers but non helped me to get what I wanted.

Like this code below generate a steam as output. I do not know how to call this function properly and how to get the Output stream as an mp3/wav file at the end.

```
    public static void Combine(string[] inputFiles, Stream output)
{
    foreach (string file in inputFiles)
    {
        Mp3FileReader reader = new Mp3FileReader(file);
        if ((output.Position == 0) && (reader.Id3v2Tag != null))
        {
            output.Write(reader.Id3v2Tag.RawData, 0, reader.Id3v2Tag.RawData.Length);
        }
        Mp3Frame frame;
        while ((frame = reader.ReadNextFrame()) != null)
        {
            output.Write(frame.RawData, 0, frame.RawData.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any one going to answer it? Please !!

Comment: When you say merge two files, you want them combined together at equal volume from the start? Or you want to put one at the end of the the other?

Comment: I want to merger them in a way that both will play together. Its like i want to mix a user's recording in a music using c# code.

Comment: Here's an article about mixing WAV files in C# this would probably be a good start for you. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35725/C-WAV-file-class-audio-mixing-and-some-light-audio

Comment: Also could you please confirm that the output should be a file or an audio stream to the sound-card output?

Comment: i want to save it as an mp3 or wav file so that it can be heard again and again.

Comment: Appreciate your help.

Comment: No worries @Ali, just trying to edit the question so that you get the best answers possible :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Simon you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you took the code from http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2010/11/merging-mp3-files-with-naudio-in-c-and.html.  Check out http://markheath.net/post/mixing-and-looping-with-naudio as well.  This talks about looping as well as mixing.  Since you're not looping, you don't need that part.

Note that the example there sends the audio to the speaker.  However, you can always replace that output with a (e.g.) `WaveFileWriter`.

Note also that the `MixingWaveProvider32` requires that all inputs be in the same `WaveFormat`.  If that's not the case, then you'll need to use a resampler.  Luckily, there's http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2014/05/how-to-resample-audio-with-naudio.html to help you out there as well.

Comment: can you please share a sample code how can i output as an mp3 or wav file using this 'WaveFileWriter' ?